# Class method "+sharedDelegate" not found

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my AppDelegete.m I've declared,

```
+(AppDelegate*) sharedDelegate
{
  return(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
}


AppDelegate  *appDelegate;

appDelegate=[AppDelegate sharedDelegate];  <= warning
```

But,

It shows warning "Class method '+sharedDelegate' not found - return type defaults to id".I tried but not fixed.

How do I hide this warning?

Comment: Have you imported `AppDelegate.h` on the class you're trying to use `+ sharedDelegate`? Also, have you declared the method on the header file?

Comment: "Hide this warning" usually isn't want you want to do :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- First declare the method in your **Header file**
- Import the **AppDelegate.h** file where you intent to use

  ```
  AppDelegate *appDelegate;

  appDelegate = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate];
  ```

Comment: You really don't need this type cast.